# How can I handle missing values in the dictionary when I use the function eval(String dictionary) -> dictionary PYTHON?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary, eval

I need to convert the ‘content’ column from a string dictionary to a dictionary in python. After that I will use the following line of code:

df[‘content’].apply(pd.Series).

To have the dictionary values as a column name and the dictionary value in a cell.

I can’t do this now because there are missing values in the dictionary string.

How can I handle missing values in the dictionary when I use the function eval(String dictionary) -> dictionary?

[I'm working on the 'content' column that I want to convert to the correct format first, I tried with the eval() function, but it doesn't work, because there are missing values. This is json data.

My goal is to have the content column data for the keys in the column titles and the values in the cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CsIl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use **json.loads** in lambda function. if row value is nan, pass, if not, apply json.loads:
:

```
import json
import numpy as np
df['content']=df['content'].apply(lambda x: json.loads(x) if pd.notna(x) else np.nan)
```

now you can use **pd.Series**.

```
v1 = df['Content'].apply(pd.Series)
df = df.drop(['Content'],axis=1).join(v1)
```

if you have missing values in string dictionaries:

```
def check_json(x):
    import ast
    import json
    if pd.isna(x):
        return np.nan
    else:
        try:
            return json.loads(x)
        except:
            try:
                mask=x.replace('{','').replace('}','') #missing dictionary
                mask=mask.split(",")
                for i in range(0,len(mask)):
                    if not len(mask[i].partition(":")[-1]) > 0:
                        print(mask[i])
                        mask[i]=mask[i] + '"None"' # ---> you can replace None with what do you want 
                return json.loads(str({','.join(mask)}).replace("\'", ""))
            except:
                try:
                    x=x.replace("\'", "\"")
                    mask=x.replace('{','').replace('}',"") #missing dictionary
                    mask=mask.split(",")
                    for i in range(0,len(mask)):
                        if not len(mask[i].partition(":")[-1]) > 0:
                            print(mask[i])
                            mask[i]=mask[i] + '"None"' # ---> you can replace None with what do you want 
                    b=str({','.join(mask)}).replace("\'", "")
                    return ast.literal_eval(b)
                except:
                    print("Could not parse json object. Returning nan")
                    return np.nan

df['content']=df['content'].apply(lambda x: check_json(x))

v1 = df['Content'].apply(pd.Series)
df = df.drop(['Content'],axis=1).join(v1)
```

Comment: Hi, '{"score":2,"leveldata":}' I put you an example of the dictionary I have with missing values. How do I put a value for leveldata on top?

Comment: The function works well. Then, the following line of code:

df['content']=df['content'].apply(lambda x: check_json(x))

I get the following error:

JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 12 (char 11)

Comment: I edited the function for general solutions. If the json cannot be parsed it will not throw an error and will fill that row as nan.

Answer (score -1):

I cannot see what the missing values look like in your screenshot, but i tested the following code and got what seems to be a good result. The simple explanation in to use str.replace() to fix the null values before parsing the string to dict.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json

## setting up an example dataframe. note that row2 has a null value
json_example = [
    '{"row1_key1":"row1_value1","row1_key2":"row1_value2"}',
    '{"row2_key1":"row2_value1","row2_key2": null}'
    ]

df= pd.DataFrame()

df['Content'] = json_example

## using string replace on the string representation of the json to clean it up

df['Content'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('null','"0"'))

## using lambda x to first load the string into a dict, then applying pd.Series()

df['Content'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(json.loads(x)))
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKZ7L.png)

Comment: Hi, 

'{"score":2,"leveldata":}'

I put you an example of the dictionary I have with missing values. How do I put a value for leveldata on top?

Comment: maybe try something like the following. The point is you're using string replace to input values in the string before parsing to dict: ('{"score":2,"leveldata":}').replace(':}',':"somevalue"}')